# RetrieveSalesforceObjects no working in text response International long code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I'm coming across a strange issue. Texting companystop to a international long code that runs this code

```
You have been unsubscribed
%%[VAR @mobilenumber,@rc,@rows SET @mobilenumber = [MOBILE_NUMBER] 
SET @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'ID, et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__c',
 'MobilePhone', '=', @mobilenumber,'MC_Sync__c', '=', 'True')
SET @rc = RowCount(@rows)]%%
```

throws 'There was an error processing your message'

However, the same code works when calling this via QueueMO API, and in fact the RetrieveSalesforceObjects part works in a cloudpage.
If I remove the RetrieveSalesforceObjects I get the text.

**Any ideas why the manual text response to an international code behaves differently compared to an API call** ? 
I didn't have this problem with the short codes.

Comment: I would debug this by printing the mobile_number to ensure its what is expected

Comment: Thanks for your tip, the phone is printed. It's the call RetrieveSalesforceObjects what breaks the code but I have no idea why, working with API, very odd, I am following up with support.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce support states the following:

Our internal team has confirmed that your long code is not intended for two way traffic and hence that is the reason you are getting the error.